# Solr 3.6: Boolean query, how do I get solr to exceed a threshold before returning results

Tags: solr, lucene

I am running a Boolean range query with lots of OR operators (close to 100). I'd like to get Apache Solr to return a result only after exceeding say 60% of matches, how do I do that?
Is it something in solrconfig or a query param?

I am looking for The Solr equivalent of `setMinimumNumberShouldMatch` in Lucene.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe [Dismax](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin#mm_.28Minimum_.27Should.27_Match.29) and [Extended Dismax](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtendedDisMax#mm_.28Minimum_.27Should.27_Match.29) query parser plugins allow you to set a minimum match value.
This documentation also talks about [Min Number Should match Specification Format](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_1_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/util/doc-files/min-should-match.html) for Solr 4.1

The query element you are looking for is `mm`, and can be set to a number of terms or a percentage, such as `mm=3` to match at least three terms, or `mm=60%` to match at least 60% of terms.

So your query should look something like:

```
(domain)/solr/select/?q=query+incorporating+a+whole+bunch+of+optional+terms&defType=edismax&mm=60%
```